# How to close side menu once list item has been clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to close a off-canvas menu when a list item is clicked.

So firstly a user toggles the menu open, then they click on a link which then closes the menu. Working code is below.

It's worth noting that I'm using CSS transitions to animate the slide and I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Jquery.

```
<nav class="menu-side mobile">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         (function() {
            var body = $('body');
            $('.menu-toggle').bind('click', function(){
                body.toggleClass('menu-open');
                    return false;

            });

         $('menu-side li').on('click', function (){
        $(".menu-side").hide();
    });

         })(); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$('menu-side li').on('click', function (){
```

Should be:

```
$('.menu-side li').on('click', function (){
```

You fotgot the **DOT**.

Comment: super. staring at it for too long. If I want to ease it out or via a slide do i pass that in the brackets of hide `.hide(here?)`

Comment: `$(".menu-side").hide();` just hides the element, it doesn't perform any animation. `slideToggle` does.

Comment: I thought `$(".menu-side").hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);`would work. But it didn't.